# Why wont this second integral compute?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why isnt my mathematica code integrating the second integral? Fairly lost as to why it will not. Trying to find an E field for an electromagnetism problem. There is a closed formed, I've seen it in the problem booklet. I was just trying to speed up my computations by learning mathematica.

input

```
f[r_] = Subscript[\[Sigma], o]/(4*Pi*Subscript[\[Epsilon], o])*
Integrate[
Integrate[(z*OverHat[z] - s*OverHat[s])/Sqrt[z^2 + s^2], {\[Phi], 
0, 2*\[Pi]}], {s, 0, R}]
```

output

stuck with the second integral not integrating

Comment: Questions like "Why won't Mathematica compute this integral analytically?" aren't really appropriate here unless there is at least some minimal justification of why you think a closed form result exists, and why Mathematica should be expected to find it.

Comment: (Please add this justification even if you think that it is obvious—it takes time for people to look at your integral and decide this.)

Comment: Ill take care of that, I apologize.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

You are using `OverHat[s]` and treating it as a separate variable. Mathematica does not know that this is how it's supposed to be interpreted. It thinks that `OverHat` is a function/operator and won't be able to carry out the integral because it does not know the definition of this function.  It is generally best to avoid things like `Subscript`, `OverHat`, etc. and use plain symbols.

The other problem is that you have lots of parameters, which in general can be any complex number.  Help Mathematica out by providing [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html).

```
Integrate[(2 π (-s hs + z hz))/Sqrt[
 s^2 + z^2] , {s, 0, R}, Assumptions -> (R > 0)]
(* ConditionalExpression[π (2 hs Sqrt[z^2] - 
    2 hs Sqrt[R^2 + z^2] - hz z Log[z^2] + 
    2 hz z Log[R + Sqrt[R^2 + z^2]]), 
 R < Im[z] || R + Im[z] < 0 || Re[z] != 0] *)

Integrate[(2 π (-s hs + z hz))/Sqrt[
 s^2 + z^2] , {s, 0, R}, 
 Assumptions -> (Element[hs | hz | z, Reals] && R > 0)]
(* ConditionalExpression[
 2 π (-hs Sqrt[R^2 + z^2] + hs Abs[z] + 
    hz z Log[(R + Sqrt[R^2 + z^2])/Abs[z]]), z != 0] *)

Integrate[(2 π (-s hs + z hz))/Sqrt[
 s^2 + z^2] , {s, 0, R}, 
 Assumptions -> (Element[hs | hz, Reals] && z > 0 && R > 0)]
(* 2 π (hs (z - Sqrt[R^2 + z^2]) + 
   hz z Log[(R + Sqrt[R^2 + z^2])/z]) *)
```

Comment: The only necessary assumptions appear to be `R > 0 && Re[z] != 0`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 That's true, but as this is a physics problem, it was reasonable to assume that all parameters are real.